# How to setup wampserver to be accessible on the internet

Tags: dns

Is it possible? I just want to access my files on the pc when I'm outside. Is it possible using dyndns or any other free service on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

DYNDNS is only needed if you do not have static IP addresses.  Based on your mentioning of dyndns, is it safe to assume you have dynamically assigned IPs?

DNS is only one part of the problem.  Whom ever you go through for Internet, you have to make sure that the inbound ports (inbound to you) are not filtered.  Many cable companies will block inbound port 80 on residential connections.  Comcast, for example, has a business class connection here in South East Michigan for around $85/month and you get 5 static and unfettered IPs.

Additionally, many cable/ISP providers supply cable modems that do some sort of NAT and firewalling so beyond what the provider does at their end, you may also need to set up what is called a port forwarding rule.  If your WAMP server has an RFC1918 address (one that starts with 192.168 or 10. or 172.16, etc..) then you have to deal with this within your device (Cable modem, DSL router, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have wamp installed and configured?  It is a pretty simple point and click installer.  The next step is to check if it is running properly by going to http://127.0.0.1; which is your local machine.  It should display the default configuration page provided by WAMP.  After that, you have to check your firewalls to make sure that it allows incoming traffic to port 80.  Depending on your setup, that step can get complicated.  If you computer is connect directly to the internet then all you need to do is configure the Windows firewall and test your web-server using your IP address.  It should display the same page.  Finally, you can add multiple directories to the WAMP/Apache server using a few simple directives:

```
Alias /MyFiles/ "C:\path\to\files\"
<Directory "C:\path\to\files\">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Although, I don't recommend putting any valuable information in those folders as anyone might be able to access them if you do not password protect them.  Also, DynDNS would allow you to create a domain name to access your computer, but you have to remember to log in every month or they will drop your domain.  I recommend using an IP address unless you are looking for a more permanent solution.