# How to electronically determine if ISP assigns DHCP addresses in RFC1918 range

Tags: dhcp, isp, static-ip, private-network

Is there an electronic method/protocol/public-website that I can use
to definitively determine whether or not my ISP assigns ([RFC1918](https://superuser.com/a/108351/106977),
[Private_network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network)) addresses for DHCP assigned addresses?

I currently have a static IP address so I cannot use the usual methods
to determine this myself from the LAN side.

When I asked the ISP's technical support, they say they cannot
determine the range, which seems odd to me. Hence my question for some
electronic method.

Comment: The helpdesk might have meant that they (helldesk, not ISP) could not determine that since they lacked knowledge about the product they provide and the lack internal communications.  Previous experience with ISP helpdesks show this to be quite common.

Comment: +1 for that. I still would like an answer to whether or not it is possible to obtain an answer via technical means versus having to be at the mercy of the ISP's willingness to dig into their network configuration to provide me an answer.

Comment: If they do not answer your DHCP requests or other configuration methods (e.g. because they are not supposed to answer it because you have a static IP address) then the only methods I see are 1) ISP 2) friends with no static address and the same provider 3) Google. Neither of those is a technical solution.

Comment: Agreed. +1 for that.  I'm going to leave this question open in hope that someone can provide an electronic means.